# Convert lists of IP's in a string to array

Tags: php, arrays, html

I am having a test file which contains the list of IP's in a new line on the server i am using phpseclib to get the file , which is been returned to me in form of string. I want to store each ip separately in an array.

I have already used

```
$arr = print_r(explode(" ",$str))
```

but it is pushing all data into $arr[0];

```
Array ( [0] => 10.54.58.1 10.54.58.27 10.54.58.28 10.54.58.31 10.54.58.32 10.54.58.33 10.54.58.36 10.54.58.45 10.54.58.60 10.54.58.67 10.54.58.80 10.54.58.86 10.54.58.89 10.54.58.97 10.54.58.98 10.54.58.99 )
```

When i tried by copying and storing them explicitly into a string and then use explode i am getting it fine.

```
Array ( [0] => 10.54.58.1 [1] => 10.54.58.27 [2] => 10.54.58.28 [3] => 10.54.58.31 [4] => 10.54.58.32 [5] => 10.54.58.33 [6] => 10.54.58.36 [7] => 10.54.58.45 [8] => 10.54.58.60 [9] => 10.54.58.67 [10] => 10.54.58.80 [11] => 10.54.58.86 [12] => 10.54.58.89 [13] => 10.54.58.97 [14] => 10.54.58.98 [15] => 10.54.58.99 )
```

Can anyone tell me what is the issue , i even tried removing the last extra space which i was getting

Comment: What does the original data look like exactly?

Comment: is the character between the ip addresses indeed one whitespace? Not a tab or new line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without your original string this is guess work, but could it be that it's a IP per line? If so, you need to explode on newline `\n`.

If you  `echo "A\nB\nC";` it will *appear like spaces* between `A B C`, but *those are newlines*. If you view the source of the page, you'll see them listed:

```
A  
B  
C
```

Therefor you need to explode on those:

```
$arr = print_r(explode("\n",$str));
```

Comment: Thank You actually it should be like explode("\n",$str)

Answer (score 0):

There is where are you wrong:

`$arr = print_r(explode(" ",$str))`

The `print_r()` function as [PHP.net says](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

> Prints human-readable information about a variable

You just want variable as it is, not information about it. Simply do

`$arr = explode(" ", $str);`

Comment: I think he is using the print_r to validate wether or not the value is as expected, debugging it

Answer (score -1):

```
$ips = $dataArray[0];

$ipArray = explode(" ",$ips);
```

On the safe side, check if index exists or not using `array_key_exists(0,$dataArray)`.